# Handle with d3.json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to make a d3 scatterplot recurring to json data. I know that d3 has d3.json to load json data but my code isn't working. I'm not that good dealing with js (it's my first time with this language), that's why I need help in this.
Basically, I need to plot this data (date in xAxis and IADP_mGycm2 in yAxis):

```
[
    {
        "imageID": 1,
        "value": 288.3,
        "date": "2015-10-22"
    },
    {
        "imageID": 2,
        "value": 188.1,
        "date": "2015-10-22"
    }
]
```

JS:

```
var margin = { top: 50, right: 300, bottom: 50, left: 50 },
outerWidth = 1050,
outerHeight = 500,
width = outerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
height = outerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]).nice();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]).nice();

var xCat = "date",
    yCat = "value";


d3.json("CR.json", function(error, rawData) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return;
    }

    var data = rawData.map(function (d) {
        return {
            date: d.date,
            value: d.value

        }
    });


    var xMax = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d["date"]; }),
        xMin = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d["date"]; }),
        xMin = xMin > 0 ? 0 : xMin,
        yMax = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d["value"]; }) ,
        yMin = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d["value"]; }),
        yMin = yMin > 0 ? 0 : yMin;

    x.domain([xMin, xMax]);
    y.domain([yMin, yMax]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .tickSize(-height);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .tickSize(-width);

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr("class", "d3-tip")
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function(d) {
        return xCat + ": " + d["date"] + "<br>" + yCat + ": " + d["value"];
      });

    var zoomBeh = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .x(x)
      .y(y)
      .scaleExtent([0, 500])
      .on("zoom", zoom);

    var svg = d3.select("#scatter")
        .append("svg")
            .attr("width", outerWidth)
            .attr("height", outerHeight)
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
            .call(zoomBeh);

    svg.call(tip);

    svg.append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    svg.append("g")
        .classed("x axis", true)
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
        .classed("label", true)
        .attr("x", width)
        .attr("y", margin.bottom - 10)
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(xCat);

    svg.append("g")
        .classed("y axis", true)
        .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
        .classed("label", true)
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", -margin.left)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(yCat);

    var objects = svg.append("svg")
      .classed("objects", true)
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    objects.append("svg:line")
      .classed("axisLine hAxisLine", true)
      .attr("x1", 0)
      .attr("y1", 0)
      .attr("x2", width)
      .attr("y2", 0)
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

    objects.append("svg:line")
      .classed("axisLine vAxisLine", true)
      .attr("x1", 0)
      .attr("y1", 0)
      .attr("x2", 0)
      .attr("y2", height);

    objects.selectAll(".dot")
        .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .classed("dot", true)
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.value; })
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.date; })
      .attr("transform", transform)
      .style("fill", "red")
      .on("mouseover", tip.show)
      .on("mouseout", tip.hide);

    var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
      .classed("legend", true)
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

    legend.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 3.5)
      .attr("cx", width + 20)
      .attr("fill", color);

    legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width + 26)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

    d3.select("input").on("click", change);

    function change() {
        xCat = "date";
        xMax = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d["date"]; });
        xMin = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d["date"]; });

        zoomBeh.x(x.domain([xMin, xMax])).y(y.domain([yMin, yMax]));

        var svg = d3.select("#scatter").transition();

        svg.select(".x.axis").duration(750).call(xAxis).select(".label").text("date");

        objects.selectAll(".dot").transition().duration(1000).attr("transform", transform);
    }

    function zoom() {
        svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);

        svg.selectAll(".dot")
            .attr("transform", transform);
    }

    function transform(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d["date"]) + "," + y(d["value"]) + ")";
    }

});
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Visualization</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scatter.css" charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="scatter"></div>

    <input type="button" name="xAxis" value="xAxis">

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
    <script src="scatter.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
rect {
  fill: transparent;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axisLine {
  fill: none;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.dot {
  fill-opacity: .5;
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One issue I see is that you're missing a `})` at the end of this code chunk:

```
var data = rawData.map(function (d) {
    return {
        date: d.date,
        IADP_mGycm2: d.IADP_mGycm2

    };
```

Try changing it to this:

```
 var data = rawData.map(function (d) {
    return {
             date: d.date,
             IADP_mGycm2: d.IADP_mGycm2
           }
    });
```

It also helps in debugging if you include the *specific* error message you're getting.

Comment: Thanks adila for your answer! I've changed that piece of code and now i'm getting another error: "Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute transform="translate(NaN,359.75150076783467)"

Comment: What that message is telling you is that the `x` value you're passing into the `transform` function is a `NaN`. I think it may have to do with this line:  `return "translate(" + x(d[xCat]) + "," + y(d["IADP_mGycm2"]) + ")";`. Is `xCat` defined?

Comment: Yes, it's the date. Don't know if it is easier for you but what I want to do is this plot (http://bl.ocks.org/peterssonjonas/4a0e7cb8d23231243e0e) but with my json data instead of a csv.

Comment: When you do `console.log(xCat)` in your `transform` function, does it print out `"date"` or `"Date"`? Javascript is case sensitive so it won't work if it's "Date".

Comment: I've already changed xCat in order to be "date" but the error remains. I suspect that the error is in this piece of code: .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.date; })

Answer (score 1):

Well, you define xCat as:

`var xCat = "Date"`

but your mapping function uses:

`date: d.date`

so, when you reference `d[xCat]` what you are getting is `d.Date` (which is undefined and would cause NaN) instead of `d.date`. That's all I can see with a quick look through.

You can fix this by using `d['date']` or `d.date` instead of `d[xCat]`.

Comment: I've already changed that but the error remains. I think it is because of this: .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.date; })
The date is in a format that JS doesn't understand.

Comment: I don't see that `.attr("cy", function (d) { return d.date; })` anywhere in your code... If you're still getting the same error:  `"Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute transform="translate(NaN,359.75150076783467)"` -- then the problem is in your `transform`, not your `cy` attribute.

Comment: Did you change that last transform function? `return "translate(" + x(d[xCat]) + "," + y(d["IADP_mGycm2"]) + ")";`  Change `x(d[xCat])` to `x(d["date"])`.

Comment: Yep i've already changed that but the error remains. Don't know if it is easier for you but what I want to do is this plot ( bl.ocks.org/peterssonjonas/4a0e7cb8d23231243e0e ) but with my json data instead of a csv.

Comment: I've edited the question with the correct code. I have 2 type of errors now: 

    Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cx="2015-10-22"
    Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute transform="translate(NaN,373.7819349434595)"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after looking a little further at this, I've identified a couple of problems. The main issue is that the chart you are trying to emulate has numeric values on both the x and y axes. However, you are trying to use dates. In order to do that, you have to use d3.time.scale() for the x-axis instead of a linear scale. You also have to transform the date strings from your data to date objects and use your time scale to scale your x-axis values. Here is scatter.js with the changes:

```
var margin      = { top: 50, right: 300, bottom: 50, left: 50 },
    outerWidth  = 1050,
    outerHeight = 500,
    width       = outerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    height      = outerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Use a time scale for the x-axis
var x = d3.time.scale()
          .range([0, width]).nice();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
          .range([height, 0]).nice();

var xCat = "date",
    yCat = "Dose";


d3.json("CR.json", function(error, rawData) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return;
    }

    var data = rawData.map(function(d) {
        return {
            // Create date objects, not strings
            date:        new Date(d.date),
            IADP_mGycm2: d.IADP_mGycm2
        }
    });


    var xMax = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d["date"]; }),
        xMin = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d["date"]; }),
        //xMin = xMin > 0 ? 0 : xMin,
        yMax = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d["IADP_mGycm2"]; }),
        yMin = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d["IADP_mGycm2"]; });
        //yMin = yMin > 0 ? 0 : yMin;

    x.domain([xMin, xMax]);
    y.domain([yMin, yMax]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(x)
                  .orient("bottom")
                  .tickSize(-height);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(y)
                  .orient("left")
                  .tickSize(-width);

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var tip = d3.tip()
                .attr("class", "d3-tip")
                .offset([-10, 0])
                .html(function(d) {
                    return xCat + ": " + d["date"] + "<br>" + yCat + ": " + d["IADP_mGycm2"];
                });

    var zoomBeh = d3.behavior.zoom()
                    .x(x)
                    .y(y)
                    .scaleExtent([0, 500])
                    .on("zoom", zoom);

    var svg = d3.select("#scatter")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", outerWidth)
                .attr("height", outerHeight)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
                .call(zoomBeh);

    svg.call(tip);

    svg.append("rect")
       .attr("width", width)
       .attr("height", height);

    svg.append("g")
       .classed("x axis", true)
       .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
       .call(xAxis)
       .append("text")
       .classed("label", true)
       .attr("x", width)
       .attr("y", margin.bottom - 10)
       .style("text-anchor", "end")
       .text(xCat);

    svg.append("g")
       .classed("y axis", true)
       .call(yAxis)
       .append("text")
       .classed("label", true)
       .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
       .attr("y", -margin.left)
       .attr("dy", ".71em")
       .style("text-anchor", "end")
       .text(yCat);

    var objects = svg.append("svg")
                     .classed("objects", true)
                     .attr("width", width)
                     .attr("height", height);

    objects.append("svg:line")
           .classed("axisLine hAxisLine", true)
           .attr("x1", 0)
           .attr("y1", 0)
           .attr("x2", width)
           .attr("y2", 0)
           .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

    objects.append("svg:line")
           .classed("axisLine vAxisLine", true)
           .attr("x1", 0)
           .attr("y1", 0)
           .attr("x2", 0)
           .attr("y2", height);

    objects.selectAll(".dot")
           .data(data)
           .enter().append("circle")
           .classed("dot", true)
           .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.IADP_mGycm2; })
           // Use the time scale to scale the values for the x-axis
           .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
           .attr("transform", transform)
           .style("fill", "red")
           .on("mouseover", tip.show)
           .on("mouseout", tip.hide);

    var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
                    .data(color.domain())
                    .enter().append("g")
                    .classed("legend", true)
                    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

    legend.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 3.5)
          .attr("cx", width + 20)
          .attr("fill", color);

    legend.append("text")
          .attr("x", width + 26)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) { return d; });

    d3.select("input").on("click", change);

    function change() {
        xCat = "date";
        xMax = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d["date"]; });
        xMin = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d["date"]; });

        zoomBeh.x(x.domain([xMin, xMax])).y(y.domain([yMin, yMax]));

        var svg = d3.select("#scatter").transition();

        svg.select(".x.axis").duration(750).call(xAxis).select(".label").text("date");

        objects.selectAll(".dot").transition().duration(1000).attr("transform", transform);
    }

    function zoom() {
        svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);

        svg.selectAll(".dot")
           .attr("transform", transform);
    }

    function transform(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d["date"]) + "," + y(d["IADP_mGycm2"]) + ")";
    }
});
```

This gets rid of the errors you were seeing, but it still doesn't plot the circles correctly. Sorry, I don't have the time to work all that out. However, this should move you forward and get you closer to figuring it out yourself. To learn more about time scales, see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales. Also, if you really want to learn D3, I highly recommend the book *D3.js in Action* by Elijah Meeks. https://www.manning.com/books/d3-js-in-action. One of the better programming books I have read.

Comment: Thanks anyway @JeffKillbride
Just one more question: my json file has 100 000 entries. Is there any way to reduce the loading time of this json? (the chart becames to slow)

Comment: Have you tried putting it in a database instead of a file? Also, svg is not the best implementation for large amounts of data, because each piece of data is represented by a dom element. Lots of data creates lots of dom elements, which tends to slow down the chart. The other thing you can do is use the canvas element. If you are using really large amounts of data in your charting, you should read this: http://www.visualcinnamon.com/2015/11/learnings-from-a-d3-js-addict-on-starting-with-canvas.html

Comment: Yes, the data is in a database and the web service generates the json that I am working on. Ok, I will follow your advice and learn more about canvas, thanks.